# Recursive SQL Query (Nullable children)

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have been working on a recursive SQL query for my referral program which i am having good success with however there is ONE issue that i am trying to resolve.  I have a Parent / Child relationship which is defined in the following Table Schema:

- Id (PK, UniqueIdentifier, Not Null)
- ReferrerMemberId (FK, uniqueidentifier, not null)
- ReferreeEmail (nvarchar(256, not null)
- ReferreeFirstName (nvarchar(50), not null)
- ReferreeMemberId (FK, uniqueidentifier, null)
- DateRedeemed (datetime, null)

This database table is designed that is there is no ReferreeMemberId (i.e. null) then i want to display the child relationship with null data.  The SQL query below will only show child elements where the ReferreeMemberId is NOT NULL.  If i can get some assistance to modify the below SQL that would be appreciated.  I would therefore like to display the record of the "incomplete" referral which is when there is a null **referreememberid** and **dateredeemed** is also null.

When trying to perform an outer query or left outer query then i get the following error:

**Outer join is not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'HierarchyTraaversal'.**

```
    DECLARE @TopLevel INT = 1    -- Top level manager (node)
    ,@NumLevels   INT = 10;   -- Depth of the hiearchy to traverse

WITH HierarchyTraaversal AS
(
    -- rCTE anchor: retrieve the top level node
    SELECT [Level]=1, a.DateRedeemed, a.ReferrerMemberId, u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName as Referrer, u.PhotoUrl as ReferrerPhotoUrl, a.ReferreeMemberId, ub.FirstName + ' ' + ub.LastName as Referree, ub.PhotoUrl as ReferreePhotoUrl
        ,ReferrerReferree=CAST(ReferrerMemberId AS VARCHAR(8000)) + '/' + CAST(ReferreeMemberId AS VARCHAR(8000))
    FROM dbo.Referrals as a
    JOIN Member as m on a.ReferrerMemberId = m.Id
    JOIN Member as mb on a.ReferreeMemberId = mb.Id
    JOIN AspNetUsers as u on m.AspNetUserId = u.Id
    JOIN AspNetUsers as ub on mb.AspNetUserId = ub.Id
    WHERE ReferrerMemberId = '914A67C8-476D-E511-9BDC-14DAE91525CD'


    UNION ALL

    -- rCTE recursion: retrieve the following nodes
    SELECT [Level]+1, a.DateRedeemed,a.ReferrerMemberId, u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName as Referrer, u.PhotoUrl as ReferrerPhotoUrl, a.ReferreeMemberId, ub.FirstName + ' ' + ub.LastName as Referree, ub.PhotoUrl as ReferreePhotoUrl
        ,ReferrerReferree=ReferrerReferree + '/' + CAST(a.ReferreeMemberId AS VARCHAR(8000))
    FROM dbo.Referrals a
    JOIN HierarchyTraaversal b ON b.ReferreeMemberId = a.ReferrerMemberId
    JOIN Member as m on a.ReferrerMemberId = m.Id
    JOIN Member as mb on a.ReferreeMemberId = mb.Id
    JOIN AspNetUsers as u on m.AspNetUserId = u.Id
    JOIN AspNetUsers as ub on mb.AspNetUserId = ub.Id
    WHERE [Level] < @NumLevels --+ 1

)
SELECT [Level], DateRedeemed, ReferrerMemberId, Referrer, ReferrerPhotoUrl, ReferreeMemberId, ReferrerReferree, Referree, ReferreePhotoUrl
FROM HierarchyTraaversal
ORDER BY [Level], ReferrerMemberId, ReferreeMemberId;
```

Comment: If you provide a good sample data and your expected result, there will be a good chance that somebody would be able to write the correct query.

Comment: It seems to me that if you change the where clause in your base case to `where ReferrMemberID is null` that it should work. Also, as a matter of style, I'd move anything not directly involved in materializing the hierarchy out of the CTE so you only have to express those joins once.